# How to register more than one version of the same variable within a session

Tags: php, session, session-variables

My website has a database which includes thousands of part numbers. These part numbers are called in to a standard template page using the variable '$pn' to make each page unique when a user searches the product.

For example, where the code states the variable ($pn) within the template, it actually populates the front-end page with the part number from my database such as 'ABC123'.

So the backend looks something like:

```
Thanks for searching for the $pn, we have this item in stock.
```

And the front-end looks something like:

```
Thanks for searching for the ABC123, we have this item in stock.
```

I would like to know how I can create a button which saves the current state of $pn (for example ABC123) to the session, then when the user visits a different part number page such as 'DEF456' they can press the button again and save a second state to the session.

The reason I would like to save the data is so that the user can browse the site and build a list of products that they are interested in on a seperate page. Similar to a basket, except the stored values would just need to add to a form field for sending.

I only need this data to be saved per session, I don't need it to be saved as a cookie to be stored for any longer than one session, or within a database for cross-browser storage.

I did try the cookie approach, but using the $pn variable as my cookie value simply erased the last state of the value and created a new value every time I visited a different part number page.

I have searched around for a solution to this, but I can't find the correct answer for me. So far I have got something like:

```
       <?php
        session_start();
        ?>

        <?php

        $pn = $item['pn'];

        // Set session variables
        $_SESSION["partnumber1"] = "$pn";
        $_SESSION["partnumber2"] = "$pn"; //Obviously at the moment this would just overwrite partnumber1 twice so I need a way to register more than once 

        ?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this which makes it a bit difficult to give you any concrete suggestions. You should ask yourself what you want to keep the data for. Do you want to only keep it per visit (session) or do you want to keep it for a longer period (cookies) or do you even want to save it between browers and for a really long time (database).

Comment: Hi @DirkScholten Thanks for your input, I have edited my question to explain the reason why I need to store the data.

Comment: Use array for storing, get parts `$parts = $_SESSION['parts'];`, add part `$parts[] = $pn;` and store to session `$_SESSION['parts'] = $parts;`, loop over parts with foreach

Comment: Thanks @Eakethet much appreciated. Would it be possible for you to show me an example of how the code should look as I am having trouble

Comment: @NickM nah, late, but ive tried small example with usage of oop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, here is small example of using session for storing array in it.

Theres class Parts. You can put it in separate file and include it everywhere, where you need it. For separate file use the part bellow your code and above example - code between brackets after class Parts...

```
<?php

session_start();

//your code

class Parts {
    private $storage = [];

    public function __construct() {
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }
        // Ref to session, you can access it directly, but if you want to change place, where parts should be stored, you can simply change it here without editing another lines of code
        $this->storage = &$_SESSION['parts'];
    }

    public function addPart($part) {
        if ($this->storage === null || !in_array($part, $this->storage)) {
            $this->storage[] = $part;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function removePart($part) {
        $this->storage = array_filter($this->storage, function($a) use ($part) { return $a !== $part; });
        return $this;
    }

    public function getParts() {
        return $this->storage;
    }

    public function setParts($parts) {
        $this->storage = $parts;
        return $this;
    }
}

$parts = new Parts();
$parts
    ->addPart(1)
    ->addPart(2)
    ->addPart(3)
    ->removePart(2);

var_dump($parts->getParts());

$allParts = $parts->getParts();

// Iterate over each part in storage
foreach ($allParts as $part) {
    // echo one part
    echo $part;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a small example of a possible solution for your problem. But like I said in my comment, there are quite a few different ways to do it. Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction.

The idea in this code is that we keep an array with all the visited parts as keys. If we see that a part is already set in our array we update the value so we can keep track of how many times they visited each part. If it is not set yet we add the element and set the counter to 1.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['parts'][$pn])){
    $_SESSION['parts'][$pn]++;
} else {
    $_SESSION['parts'][$pn] = 1;
}
```

Now if you want to do something with the array you can do that like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['parts'] as $key => $value) {
    echo 'you have visited part' . $key . ' a total of ' . $value . 'times';
    //You can do whatever you want with the information here.
}
```